# Distinct values from while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a field called part_name.
with the values:

```
Front Control Arm, Rear Control Arm
```

I need to echo out only Control Arm, once only. 
As of now what i'm getting on the while loop results is

```
Control Arm, Control Arm.
```

Need to echo out distinct values from while loop results. I can't do it on the SQL query `SELECT DISTINCT` because i'm preg replacing the value from the row that i'm queering on the database.

```
while ($rowsparts = mysql_fetch_array($displayparts))    {
     $part=''.$rowsparts['part_name'].''; 
     $part = preg_replace('/\bFront\b/u', '', $part);
     $part = preg_replace('/\bRear\b/u', '', $part);  
     echo '<li>'.$part.'</li>';
}
```

I need to echo out the $part variable distinct values, only once per part name.

Control Arm only.

Comment: You can do regex replace in the MySQL query as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem With native mysql functions?

Comment: @chris85: nope with a custom defined one.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This is my sql query:
 $selectparts="SELECT * FROM association RIGHT JOIN parts ON association.part_id = parts.id WHERE association.vehicle_id=".$id." AND parts.category='$category' GROUP BY part_name ORDER BY part_name ASC LIMIT 8";

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How could i do that ? Any ideas please?

Comment: Are there multiple terms or just these two? You could use `replace`, like `replace(replace(column, 'Front Control Arm', 'Control Arm'), 'Rear Control Arm', 'Control Arm')`. Your regex can also be simplified to `\b(Rear|Front)\b`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem there are multiple terms, please check the website http://www.imricardo.com/vehicle/2004/BMW/325i/2.5L.html

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This might work if you want to only display the part name once:

```
$lastpart = '';
while ($rowsparts = mysql_fetch_array($displayparts)) {
    $part = $rowsparts['part_name']; 
    $part = trim(str_replace('Rear','',str_replace('Front','',$part)));
    if($lastpart != $part) {
        $lastpart = $part;
        echo "<li>".$part."</li>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<li>Part name duplicate: $part, lastpart: $lastpart</li>\n";
    }
}
```

I added the **else** for debugging. It will show the two vars that are used to detect duplicates. You would remove it after testing.

This might work if you want to only display the part name once when the part names are not in order. 
It builds a list of part names, and checks each part names against the list, showing 
only the ones not found in the list.

```
$part_list = array();
while ($rowsparts = mysql_fetch_array($displayparts)) {
    $part = $rowsparts['part_name']; 
    $part = trim(str_replace('Rear','',str_replace('Front','',$part)));
    if(!isset($part_list[$part])) {
        $part_list[$part] = 1;
        echo "<li>".$part."</li>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: it ain't working with code you gave me, is still echoing duplicate part names

Comment: Can you give an example of how it's not working? That is, a short list of records retrieved and the resulting output?

Comment: Please go to the live website @ http://www.imricardo.com/vehicle/2004/BMW/325i/2.5L.html

Comment: For this approach you would need to `order by` the `part_name`. This isn't the most efficient approach. Doing it in SQL will be better.

Comment: @user3740456, the link is somewhat helpful, but has too much "noise". I changed the code above to provide some "debug" info. Try to create a simple example page (not part of the site's menu) that will show just the problem area.

Comment: It's working now, but only with the first result. If you look at my website on the 3rd result (Body Electrical) is echoing Tail Lamp twice

Comment: Because they are out of order. It will only work if the part names are adjacent. @chris85 is right, this should be done in the SQL statement. If you need to persist a list of names out of order to eliminate duplicates, that can be done, but requires that you build a list of part names. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: I can't build a list of part names because there are just too many of them. If i do it on the SQL statement them it will echo: Right Lower Control Arm, Left Lower Control Arm, Upper Control Arm, etc etc.

Comment: I've updated the answer above to remove duplicate names (after modification) even when not adjacent.

Comment: It's working perfectly now Sloan! Thank you so much, even though i'm not an expert i do my best and try to resolve issues by myself when i'm stuck with a code not working the way i want it before i ask for help.

Comment: No. In the SQL statement you would create an extra field that holds the modified part name. If all you are removing from the names is Right, Left, Front, Rear, that could be done easily. Your order by would use that instead of the real part name. If you are using one SQL for all of the parts, your order by would be something like ORDER BY `category`,`short_part_name` with that last bit being the calculated column. If you show your existing SQL select statement, that would help.